# Connecting Flatten layer to Dense layer

Tags: neural-network, keras, lstm, rnn

I'm struggling with my neural network.

In short, I need to recreate a model from anywhere on the internet, I've found a model that combines BiLSTM, LSTM and GRU. However, based on the error I got when trying to train the model, I suspect that I need to add Flatten layer before Dense layer. But I don't understand what size I should put into this layer, because when I simply add `Flatten()` before first Dense layer, I get:  `ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to a Dense layer should be defined. Found None. Full input shape received: (None, None)`

The NN without Flatten() is below.

[image]